# Prove that there are infinitely many primes of the form $8k + 3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Prove that there are infinitely many primes of the form $8k + 3$

I have seen proofs for $4k+1$ and $8k+1$ and $4k+3$ but struggling with this one please help

The suggestion given is to consider a number of the form $N^2+2$ how did one decide this is the one to work with.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Method $1$** using **Dirichlet's Theorem**  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions

Dirichlet asserts that whenever $(a, b) = 1$ and a not zero the sequence $an + b$ contains infinitely many primes.

$(8,3)=1$ so there are infinitely many primes of the form $8k+3$

**Method $2$**

By the hint from lhf

Let primes of the form $8k+3$ be finite and denoted by $p_1, \dots, p_n$

Let $N=p_1 p_2\cdots p_n$.

consider $M=N^2+2$.  Clearly none of the $p_i$ divide $M$. Let $q$ be a prime factor of $M$ so $N^2\equiv-2\pmod q$.

By quadratic Residue principles we can say $\left(\frac{-2}q\right)$ which is same as $\left(\frac2q\right)*\left(\frac{-1}q\right)$
by using formula for these two we can say $q\equiv1\pmod2$ and $q^2\equiv1\pmod8$ so we can try for $q\equiv1,3,5,7\pmod8$ the conditions are satisfied for only 1 and 3.

we can say the $q\equiv1\pmod8$ implies $q$ must be of the form $8k+1$

$q\equiv3\pmod8$ implies $q$ must be of the form $8k+3$.

we know each $p_i\equiv3\pmod8$

$N=p_1 p_2\cdots p_n\equiv3^n\pmod8$

$N^2\equiv3^{2n}\equiv(3^2)^n\equiv9^n\equiv1\pmod8$

as $M=N^2+2$

$M\equiv3\pmod8$

we know all the  divisors ($q$) of $M$ must be of the form $8k+1$ or $8k+3$

let $M=r_1 r_2\cdots r_t$ where all $r_i$ are of the form $8k+1$ and all $r_i\equiv1\pmod8$ so $M\equiv1\pmod8$ which is a contradiction as we have asserted previously that $M\equiv3\pmod8$ so M cannot have all divisors in the form of $8k+1$ it should have at least one divisor of the form $8k+3$. Let this divisor be $Q$.

since $Q$ divides $M$ but its not one of the $p_i$ its contradiction hence we should have infinite primes of the form $8k+3$

Answer (score 6):

*Hint:* Let $p_1, \dots, p_n$ be primes of the form $8k+3$. Take $N=p_1^2 p_2^2\cdots p_n^2+2$. Prove that $N$ must have a prime factor of the form $8k+3$. This prime cannot be one of $p_1, \dots, p_n$ because if $p_i$ divided $N$ then it would divide $2=N-p_1^2 p_2^2\cdots p_n^2$, but $p_i$ is odd.

Comment: i got up to that much how do i proceed after this

Comment: @MRK: Looks like $-2$ is a quadratic residue modulo any prime factor of $N$. What does the reciprocity law tell you? What about $N$ modulo $8$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen still lost? sorry

Comment: What do you know, MRK, about quadratic residues? about quadratic reciprocity? If the answer is, "nothing", then you now know what you have to learn in order to understand how to do the problem.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks for patronising

Comment: @MRK I don't think that was patronising, though it could take a while to learn that if you really know nothing about the issue. Anyway, you said you got up that much as shown in the answer, so it says you know $\;N\;$ has a prime divisor of the form $\;8k+3\;$ , right? Is a problem now to show this prime can't be any of $\;p_1,...,p_n\;$ ? Is this where you're stuck?

Comment: @MRK Are you familiar with the theory of quadratic residues enough to be able to deduce that if we have a congruence $m^2\equiv-2\pmod{\ell}$ for some integer $m$ and some odd prime number $\ell$, then it follows that $\ell$ is either of the form $8k+1$ or of the form $8k+3$? This is to be applied to the prime factors of $N$.

Comment: @Timbuc yes i was stuck there exactly and still am but i still think Gerry's comments were patronising the reason for posting this question is because i need help not because i was lazy to do it myself.

Comment: I think most people here thought you were stuck at showing that $\;N\;$ has a prime divisor of the required form, but if you already have that then the finish is simple: if $\;p\;$ is the prime of the form $\;8k+3\;$ dividing $\;N\;$ , and since $\;N=2\pmod{p_i}\;,\;\;\forall \,1=1,2,...,n\;$ , it must be that $\;p\;$ is *different* from all the $\;p_1,...,p_n\;$ , and you've then proved that given any finite set of primes of the required form there's always a different one of the same form.

Comment: When you write something like, "still lost? sorry", it's extremely difficult to tell exactly what you are having trouble with, or indeed whether you understand anything in the message to which you are responding. Since Jyrki's comment mentioned quadratic residues and the reciprocity law, one interpretation of your "still lost? sorry" is that you had never heard of those concepts. I was trying to clarify whether that was indeed the situation. All you had to do was say, yes, you know about those things, but what you still don't get is .... Anyway, I was trying to help, not patronize.