# Prove that there are infinitely many primes p with p ≢ ±1 mod 8.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I understand how to prove this in the case of p is congruent to 1(mod 8) but am stuck on what to pick as a prime that is not included in a list {p1,...,pk} and can be shown to not be congruent to 1(mod 8).

Comment: Read [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1046343/prove-that-there-are-infinitely-many-primes-of-the-form-8k-3)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that there are infinitely many primes of the form $8k + 3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1046343/prove-that-there-are-infinitely-many-primes-of-the-form-8k-3)